# How can I (conditionally) format a cell based on the value NOT being one of a set of valid string values?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Suppose I have 1 column, labelled `foo`. The values for each row can be, 'a', 'b', or 'c'. A user can enter other values, like 'q' for example. But I would like to highlight that it is not part of the valid set 'a', 'b', or 'c'.

I'm assuming that a conditional formatting rule is a way to go here. But the syntax is a bit opaque, and I'm not finding helpful examples online. I speculated that perhaps

`=countifs(A:A, '<>a', A:A, '<>b', A:A, '<>c')>0`

Could do the trick. But, no luck.

Hoping some Sheets/Excel wizards out there could help point me in a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

custom formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2,"<>a",A2,"<>b",A2,"<>c",A2,"<>")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

custom formula:

```
=IF(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"a|b|c","")<>"",1)
```

[image: 0]